# Using mixin with multiple class selector

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have a mixing like this:

```
@mixin box($bgcolor:#ff00ff){
    .box{
        .inner{
            border: 1px;
               background-color:$bgcolor;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use smth like that

```
    @include box();
    blue &{
        @include box(blue);
    }
```

in order to achieve:

```
    .box .inner{
    ...       
    }
    .blue.box{
    ...       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a mixin? Try something like this:

```
.box {
  .inner, &.blue {
    border: 1px;
    background-color:$bgcolor;
  }
}
```

Especially if you only want the `inner` class on one of them.

Comment: Yes. I need a mixin. Let's say this is a mixin for a button. The structure is more complex, with more than 10 parameters and I need to have different "looks":

class="dark btn" class="happy btn" class="dropbox btn"